# How can we calculate mean?

Tags: statistics

In the [***AForge.net***](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/f492924fd60fc8cdf8f783733bbb5c120ce5c92a/Sources/Math/Statistics.cs#L47) the mean value of a vector is calculated as follows:

```
    public static double Mean( int[] values )
    {
        int     hits;
        double  total = 0;
        double  mean = 0;

        // for all values
        for ( int i = 0, n = values.Length; i < n; i++ )
        {
            hits = values[i];
            // accumulate mean
            mean += (double) i * hits;
            // accumalate total
            total += hits;
        }
        return ( total == 0 ) ? 0 : mean / total;
    }
```

I couldn't understand this.

As far as I know mean is the value where sum is divided by the count of numbers.

Can anyone explain this to me?

What does it mean by **`hits`** here?

**Can we calculate mean of real numbers  in the same way?**

Comment: This seems not be a math question. Else, we actually have something called "generalized mean" which you could find in Wikipedia.

Comment: Run the program by hand with some numbers of `values`.

Comment: Read the code comments, and pay attention to "*The* ***input array is treated as histogram*** ...".

Comment: "As far as I know mean is the value where sum is divided by the count of numbers." which is exactly what a mean is and exactly what this program does. "What does it mean by hits here?"  hits is the running tally as you add things up.  In the end hits is the sum of all the values and total is the number of values.  So this returns the sum divided by the number.  Which is the mean.  (Unless there *aren't* any values.  If there were zero values it returns $0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the program by hand with some numbers of `values`. For values=$245$

[image]

so as the code says it is `accumulate mean`: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\text{digits}}na_n$$
where $a_n$ is the $n$-th digit of input $:)$. The total is sum of digits, therefore the result is
$$\dfrac{1\times a_1+2\times a_2+3\times a_3+\cdots+n\times a_n}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}$$
for number $a_1a_2\cdots a_n$. For number $245$ the result is
$$\dfrac{1\times 2+2\times 4+3\times 5}{2+4+5}=\dfrac{25}{11}$$

Comment: Can we calculate mean of real numbers in the same way?

Comment: I don't know what the result means so I haven't any idea for your question. I just wanted to help, but the picture didn't place in the comment box ;).

Comment: It's better you add statistic or calculus to tag question @yahoo.com